# Администратор не проходит аутентификацию в mongodb при запуске spring приложения

Tags: spring, docker, mongodb

Создал spring приложение со следующей конфигурацией подключения к MongoDB в application.yml:

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: TestApp
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
      username: username
      password: password
      authentication-database: admin
```

Сам MongoDB работает в докере, запущен с помощью следующего docker compose файла:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: username
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - db_data:/data
mongo-express:
  image: mongo-express
  restart: always
  ports:
    - 8081:8081
  environment:
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: username
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
    ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://username:password@mongo:27017/
volumes:
  db_data: {}
```

Создаю entity с полями, на которые вешаю индексы. При запуске приложения получаю ошибку

> Command failed with error 13 (Unauthorized): 'Command createIndexes requires authentication' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Command createIndexes requires authentication", "code": 13, "codeName": "Unauthorized"}

Логин и пароль в application.yml соотвествуют docker-compose, я вручную смог авторизоваться в терминале. Почему spring не может пройти аутентификацию в Mongo при запуске?